# How shall I resolve a version mismatch in the out123 library?

Tags: raspbian

As I'd like to play MP3 files on my Raspi 3B, I installed mpg123 together with the libmpg123-dev package so that I can call mpg123 from some host application. However, every time I call out123_open (), I get seven identical error messages, which read as follows:

```
[src/libout123/module.c:163] error: API version of module does not match (got 1, expected 2).
```

A brief look into the out123.h header file revealed 2 as the current API version. I've got [libmpg123-dev from the sid branch](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/libmpg123-dev), as the version from the stable branch lacks the out123 files I need.

What's wrong here? Thank you for any useful hints.

Comment: Is the right header being pulled by your compiler? If you're using gcc, try `gcc -H -fsyntax-only <yourfile.c>` which will output the headers used, and edit that in your post if you can.

Comment: OK, I've got a result:
. /usr/include/mpg123.h
.. /usr/include/fmt123.h
. /usr/include/out123.h

…which is basically what I expected.

Comment: Hmm, odd. That sounds okay, but it definitely seems like your install has mixed up an older version or something. If you're running out of other options, the only idea I can suggest is the 'nuclear option' of trying a fresh OS image and installing libmpg123 again. Hopefully, though, you find a better solution.

Comment: I strongly hope I'll find a more viable solution than re-installing everything. Supposedly, the DEB packages of mpg123 are full of bugs: The libmpg123-dev package from the stable branch lacked out123.h, so I had to take the package from the sid (= unstable) branch, yet this one isn't working wither. I've also left a support request on the mpg123 mailing list, but nobody has responded so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least I've now got a workaround now: I got the sourcecode tarball from Github and compiled it myself. I know this isn't a very clean approach (especially not on production systems), but at least I've got a working mpg123 installation now.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Well, I've been hoping for a "real" solution, not just for a workaround.